# What defines an "Active user"?

Tags: support

Yearling

Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

This badge is, obviously, awarded to members who are active for a year and earn at least 200 rep. What, exactly, is an active user? Would that be someone who logs in everyday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are one thing not two. Earning 200 rep durring the year is what defines active. There are other badges that cover just logging in. Active means you are asking and/or answering at least a modicum of posts that earn a few votes.

Comment: Ahh... thank you!

Answer (score 4):

"active" simply means logging in in this sense.

If you manage to accumulate 200 rep and have been a member for a year, you'll be awarded the badge. That's active enough for SE's standards.

(You can keep getting them by earning at least 200 rep in subsequent years).